# Tor fails looking for /root/.tor

Tags: configuration, onion-services, startup

This starts up Tor correctly:

```
sudo -u debian-tor /usr/sbin/tor --runasdaemon 0 -f /etc/tor/torrc
```

But when I try the same from supervisord

```
[program:tor]

command=/usr/sbin/tor --runasdaemon 0 -f /etc/tor/torrc

user=debian-tor
```

it fails with

```
Dec 16 11:00:06.977 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".

Dec 16 11:00:06.979 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050

Dec 16 11:00:06.979 [notice] Opened Socks listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:9050

Dec 16 11:00:06.979 [warn] Directory /root/.tor cannot be read: Permission denied

Dec 16 11:00:06.979 [notice] Closing partially-constructed Socks listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:9050

Dec 16 11:00:06.979 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Couldn't create private data directory "/root/.tor"

Dec 16 11:00:06.979 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.

Tor version 0.4.7.16.
```

No idea why it looks for `/root/.tor` in this case, anyway I did

```
sudo mkdir -p /root/.tor

sudo chown debian-tor /root/.tor
```

but same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's about the $HOME environment variable that still points to the /root folder and of course it's not writable or readable by other users. To avoid that set Data directory **and** the user in `/etc/tor/torrc` config and simply launch it as root: it will drop itself to the user you've set in config ASAP after opening the port listeners, so it's safe and secure. In your case it's a wrong place to drop the privileges in your supervisord service config

Comment: Turns out supervisord only changes the userid but not $HOME.

Comment: And he should not behave otherwise! That's what the configuration files are for